# Unable to drop database mysql: ERROR 3664 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database in my application named `X-Files`.

I want to `drop` it. But whenever I run the command `drop database X-Files` I am getting following error:

`mysql> drop database X-Files;
ERROR 3664 (HY000): Failed to set SDI 'X-Files.MembersTbl' in tablespace 'x-files/memberstbl'.`

I haven't found any reference for this error yet. Also I have checked my sql server is up and running.

Comment: Try a rename the database and drop it

Comment: Check free disk space and run analyze tables: https://gist.github.com/tony4d/75d3246592dcbeb389a6

Answer (score 2):

Try to manually start your database under SystemPreferences/MySQL. I had the same issue and forgot I had unchecked the option to automatically start sql upon booting up my computer. After reinitializing the database everything began to work as expected.