# MySQL 8 - DROP or ALTER Causes ERROR 3664 (HY000): Failed to set SDI

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

```
ERROR 3664 (HY000): Failed to set SDI 'MyDatabase.MyTable' in tablespace 'mydatabase/mytable'.
```

I run into this error whenever trying to `DROP` a Database or `ALTER` a Table. I am unable to delete or alter any Table that I've created.

Now, what's really interesting is that **these errors only occur after restarting MySQL and a subsequent login (by root user) to MySQL**. Here's the pattern:

1. Login to MySQL as root user.
2. Create a Database and create Tables.
3. `DROP` the Database or `ALTER` Tables with no issues **:)**
4. Exit MySQL
5. Restart MySQL (stop then start)
6. Login to MySQL as root user.
7. Get ERROR 3664 when attempting to `DROP` the Database or `ALTER` Tables I previously created, hindering any `DROP` or `ALTER` **:(**

It seems that the restarting of MySQL allows it to recognize the new Database & Table changes and update some kind of [SDI (Serialized Dictionary Information)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/serialized-dictionary-information.html) metadata associated with my `InnoDB` Database Tables and Tablespace I want to change. Somehow this recognition of SDI info is hindering my `ALTER` and `DROP` commands. **Could this be a bug in MySQL? Or, could my root user not have permission to run commands that modify SDI data? (Although, the documentation says that SDI data is modified by an internal API.)**

This happens to me EVERY TIME I create a Database and Tables. So, **my very crippling workaround for this error**:

1. Manually delete the data files associated with the Database in the data directory.
2. Call `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS MyDatabase;` (may need to log out/in a couple times, or restart MySQL and try to access tables with `SELECT` statements for this to finally work)
3. Recreate the Database and Tables needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

---

I'm running MySQL 8.0.11 Community Server on a Mac.

The same issue with no solution: [Unable to drop database mysql: ERROR 3664 (HY000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061316/unable-to-drop-database-mysql-error-3664-hy000)

Comment: To be honest, this does not seem to be a programming issue. Either there is some config setting that needs to be set, or it is a bug. The DBA SE site would be a lot better place to ask this question because DBAs are better aware of config settings and bugs, than programmers are.

Comment: @Shadow I've added this post to the MySQL forums and will post a link if it gets approved for the forum. Thanks!

Comment: @TimArterbury did you find a way to solve this ?

Comment: @eveevans Sadly no. I posted on the MySQL forum but it seems my post was never approved. I may try to file a bug report. It's interesting such a simple error has not been caught. I'm only trying to use a basic MySQL feature of deleting a database lolz.

Comment: I think it is the bug. Single way to drop database was to delete files and then repeat drop schema.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. My only solution has been to rename the database and run my migration process. Why hasn't this been fixed? Has anyone found out a better work-around?

Comment: I got the same issue. The problem is with the foreign keys: after starting MySQL server, I try to create table C, with foreign keys pointing at tables A and B, which were previously created. I get the 3664 error on the constraint with A. A workaround is doing a select on A. If you try creating C again, this time will complain about B. Do a select on B and try again. It will work. It's almost as if the tables were not properly initialised.

Answer (score 10):

I and several of my students have been seeing this issue crop up more and more.

As a workaround I have found if you go in and do an `analyze table` on all the tables in the problem database it will fix this error until the next time you restart the server.

Comment: Hi. We are having this SDI problem too. May I know what OS you are using?

Comment: I am using High Sierra on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

This is a related patch which is in mysql-8.0.11:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/261981bdf42c110f08f98ad2cf84ce6fdef1949e

*sdi_debug.result* seems to indicate that

```
SET GLOBAL DEBUG = '-d, sdi_delete_failure';
```

is needed to overcome the issue.

Comment: Interesting. When I run the command `SET GLOBAL DEBUG = '-d, sdi_delete_failure';`, I get `ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'DEBUG'`.

Comment: @Xypron no, that's just clearing the flag used to trigger simulation of the error while running the test suite (on a debug build).  Notice how the test goes through two iterations of `+d` (set) followed by `-d` (clear).

Answer (score 1):

If you empty all of the tables, you can then drop the schema.

Interestingly, this statement works if using a PDO in PHP

```
$conn->exec("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $dbname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related to foreign keys. This statement fails:

```
CREATE TABLE `lottery` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `club_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` text,
  `open_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_lottery_club` (`club_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lottery_club` FOREIGN KEY (`club_id`) REFERENCES `club` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But if I remove the KEY and CONSTRAINT clauses, it works.

```
CREATE TABLE `lottery` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `club_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` text,
  `open_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

After the create I then have to add those keys back using ALTER TABLE.

Annoying to say the least.

Comment: I understand that the issue you bring up is present when deleting specific Tables and is due to key constraints. But rather, my issue is with deleting (DROPing) a Database.  I'm running into some kind of Tablespace issue as opposed to a foreign key issue. For the code you provided, you shouldn't get the foreign key constraint error when dropping the entire database.

Comment: I’m not getting a foreign key error. I am getting that same SDI error you are getting on dropping the whole DB.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I was getting the same "Failed to set SDI" error when attempting:

```
ALTER TABLE 'MyDb.MyTable' ADD COLUMN 'myCol' VARCHAR(255)
```

In my case the table engines were a mix of `InnoDB` and `MyISAM`. They should have all be `InnoDB` and when I switched them and restarted the MySQL server, things seemed to work.

There were a variety of `.sdi` files in MySql's data directory (`/usr/local/mysql/data/MyDb/` on my machine)... which is just a simple `json` file with metadata related to a specific table. These SDI files only seem to exist for MyISAM tables.

Before I realized this, I figured the SDI file for the specific table must be missing, or something, and it turns out that mysql has an **`ibd2sdi`** utility in its bin directory that can create an SDI file from a tables `ibd` files (which are also in the data directory).

If you need to stick with `MyISAM` it might be worth having a look at that. Be careful about modifying the contents of an SDI file, though, as I ran across [this quote in the MySql worklogs](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7524):

> Great care must be taken when doing this - changes which are not compatible with what is stored in the .MYD and .MYI files, like changing the data type of a column, would likely be disastrous and must be avoided.

Don't know if this is helpful, but thought I'd share.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

`check table table_name for upgrade`

After that, I could run my DDL statement without error.